Illustrator - Export Selection with Custom Filename instead of "Asset"?
When I export a selection, there is no field to enter a filename? It automatically names the file "Asset 1.~"
Am I overlooking something?
Exporting in general has always allowed me to name exported files without having to navigate to the destination folder and renaming in Finder. Why does Export Selection not allow this?
I just need to be able to quickly name my exported object on the fly.


In the export dialog box you can click on the word Asset-1 or Asset-2 and it will highlight and you can change the name right there.
